# Converted Web to app,multiple image selection not working

Tags: php, android, html

I have a website where user can select multiple images and upload.
I have used attribute multiple class to select multiple images

I have used webtoapp website to create app from the URL of my website.

Everything work same except the image selection.only one image at a time is selecting instead of multiple.

Is there any other attributes which can allow the input tag to select multiple images when used as Android app as well?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to write your own code using android studio or aide.

Some level code, i/o, selecting file (file chooser) sometime not easy to converting.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34572003)

Comment: Because from my experience, there still no app was build with android can serve what you asking.
i can make you a sample app that can do that. just to show you, it is not something impossible to do.